# How to reload header and footer in MS Word using officejs api

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office-js

I receive a document in ooxml format from BE using this method (and xml from BE contains the entire document, with header and footer (if they exist)):

```
public someGetMethod(templateId: string): ng.IPromise<Template[]> {
    return this.Service.getXml(templateId)
        .then((myBodyXML: string) => {
            return Word.run((...args) => {
                const context = args[0];
                const body = context.document.body;
                body.insertOoxml(myBodyXML, Word.InsertLocation.replace);

                return context.sync();
            })
                .catch((error: Error) => {
                    console.error('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
                });
        });
}
```

This works fine.

The problems begins when I choose some other document and load it again using this method, because the header and footer do not change, only the document body.

Yes, it is normal, because I use `body.insertOoxml()` and according to [the documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/document) the body does not contain the header and footer (*but how and why they have been loaded first time and don't not reload the second time?*).

I tried to get the header and footer in this way and clean it or load empty text or ooxml before I choose next template to load:

```
const mySections = context.document.sections;
context.load(mySections);
return context.sync().then(() => {
    myHeader = mySections.items[0].getHeader('primary');
    myHeader.insertOoxml(myBodyXML, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
    // or
    myHeader.clear();
    // or
    myHeader.insertText('', Word.InsertLocation.replace);
    return context.sync();
});
```

but the result is the same.

So, summing up, can anyone please answer how to reload without the pain of reloading the entire document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question and please add more details to it. Having the build number of your Office will help a lot, thanks for providing it in Github. I know you are in a Word version that only supports the Word.js 1.1 requirement set, so code can be simpler in newer builds, for now bear with me. Also in this case is also very helpful if you can include a link to the OOXML payload you are inserting, if you can add those details will help us been more effective helping you.

That been said, the way to solve your scenario is to have 3 OOXML fragments: one for the document body, another one for the header body  and another one for the footer body, you do this 3 operations separately.

Here are a few facts that will clarify how the API behaves, explain why you need to take this approach and probably guide you in the right direction.

1. First of all body.insertOoxml() by design will not replace existing headers/footers in the document, and the same is true for body.insertFileFromBase64() method. The operation only affects the body of the document. In other words, it's by design that if the to-be-inserted OOXML contains headers and footers definitions, to protect the current document they will be ignored not override existing ones. Here is a [script lab sample](https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/45e207afc5a9266dc55786671a41ded6)  (and btw [go here](http://aka.ms/scriptlab) to learn how to use script lab)that demonstrates this fact. Check out the OOXML markup that I am inserting, it contains header and footer definitions and they are **not** inserted in the document after calling document.body.insertOoxml()
2. Headers and footers are considered separate body elements (in fact in the file format are separate documents known as "sub documents"). So to insert the OOXML there, you will need separate OOXML fragments for each, something that looks like

```js
mySections.items[0].getHeader("primary").insertOoxml(ooXmlHeader, "replace");
return context.sync()
```

3. Finally clearing the headers and footers i think you are following the right approach, just make sure you traverse all the sections in the document, [here is a script lab sample](https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/98469c4775e21ec448a523d9998df7af) showing how to do this.

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Really thank you for your answer!
Yes, approach with separate inserting can works, but it is complicated to split document into 3 parts in BE side.
I tried approach from [script lab](https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/98469c4775e21ec448a523d9998df7af), problem is still here. And I do not understand why clear method clears header just visually. I mean the header is still on his place and if I manually make double click on header -> ctrl+a > delete, after that I can load next body.insertOoxml() and it is replace header also.
Is it possible to implement logic for complete header deletion?

Comment: the coded that i shared clears the workbook headers.

Comment: It`s clears but I can`t reload them by body.insertOoxml. Thank you for your help and full answer.